# setTimeout / Promise.resolve: Macrotask vs Microtask

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

I've been introduced to the concepts of Microtasks and Macrotasks for a while now, and from everything I've read, I always thought **`setTimeout`** to be considered to create a macrotask and **`Promise.resolve()`** (or `process.nextTick` on NodeJS) to create microtasks.

(Yes, I'm aware that different Promise libraries like Q and Bluebird have different schedulers implementations, but here I'm referring to the native Promises on each platform)

With this in mind I'm unable to explain the following sequence of events on NodeJS (results on Chrome are different from NodeJS (both v8 LTS and v10) and match with my understanding on this subject).

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
 setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Timeout ", i);
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
   console.log("Promise 1 ", i);
  }).then(() => {
   console.log("Promise 2 ", i);
  });
 })
}
```

So, the results I have on Chrome (and that are consistent with my understanding of Micro/Macro tasks and how Promise.resolve and setTimeout behave) are:

```
Timeout  0
Promise 1  0
Promise 2  0
Timeout  1
Promise 1  1
Promise 2  1
```

The same code executed on NodeJS outputs:

```
Timeout  0
Timeout  1
Promise 1  0
Promise 2  0
Promise 1  1
Promise 2  1
```

I'm looking for a way to have the same results on NodeJS that I have on Chrome. I've also tested with `process.nextTick` instead of `Promise.resolve()` but the results are the same.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: FWIW: When I run the example in Node a few times I see both results happen a few times. It doesn't seem to be completely consistent.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. You are correct, I had not realized that yet. That makes this even more hard to understand actually :/

Comment: Try a timeout greater than 0?

Comment: Are you just trying to get a better understanding or do you have an actual problem in real code?

Comment: @Bergi I actually tried that. Independently of the time the same problem happens.

Yes, I have a "real code" problem. Unfortunately the example itself is a bit complex and I've managed to boil it down to the code I posted on the question.

The end goal is that I need to sync an object with everything that happens inside a event loop. So that on the next loop I can serialize and send it else where.

If Node behaved as Chrome I could easily achieve that.

Comment: We have 3 microtask queues, forget about the macro task. These are setTimeout/Interval/Immediate, requestAnimationFrame and now Promises. The way things work, it should be guaranteed that the order within the SAME microtask queue is preserved, (setTimeout 1 before 2, Promise n-1 before n etc). But controlling how 2 different microtask queues are ordered, as far as I know are vendor dependent. Cannot be relied.

Comment: I posted a working snippet that solves your problem.  If you create the timeouts in a loop, you will get inconsistent results.

Comment: @ibowankenobi do you know of a way of creating MacroTasks within NodeJS?

What I need is to queue a microtask within a macrotask so that the microtask is executed before the following macrotask. Do you know a way of scheduling a MacroTask inside NodeJS (I thought setTimeout would do that but unfortunately it seems not to do that)

Comment: You will need to create a wrapper to return an object with result from setTimeout and a callback to embed the promise within.

Comment: Basically what you are asking for is async code to be forced to run in order, pretty simple to do this using async / await.

Comment: Your `Promise.resolve()` code looks like they can be executed synchronously. If so, just remove the promise and put the `console.log` directly in the `setTimeout`. If the `console.log` is an async task then this is not an issue of microtask/macrotask. It is a timing issue.

Comment: Actually, you have **6** asynchronous tasks where 2 are synced with previous one (Promise 2) so thats why you get always `Promise1 n` then `Promise 2 n`. Others are left to fate of TaskQueue..and there others things steps into game. For example Render Queue, Event Loop etc. Chrome and nodejs have same engine but are different environments. Chrome renders DOM tree, handles different events etc...and all of this can kick task scheduling like this to different directions..

Comment: @bigless Guys,I'm not sure but I think i did something close to what the OP wants, would you guys give a try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was recognized by the NodeJs team as a bug, more details here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22257

Meantime it was already fixed and released has part of Node v11.

Best,
José

Answer (score 1):

You can't control how different architectures queue the promises and timeouts.

Excellent Read Here: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

If you want the same results you are going to have to chain promises.

```js
let chain = Promise.resolve(null)

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  console.log("Chaining ", i);
  chain = chain.then(() => Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Timeout ", i);

        Promise.resolve()
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Promise 1 ", i);
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Promise 2 ", i);
          })

      }, 0)
    }))
}

chain.then(() => console.log('done'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a simplified example. I cannot change the setTimeout inside the for. What I can change is the Promise.resolve() within the setTimeout.

Comment: It seems the problem is that setTimeout is running differently on both platforms.

Comment: You can still call setTimeout, just do it once.

Comment: Please see working snippet.  Node and Chrome handle timeouts in loop with 0 delay differently.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
In fact the issue is not with the setTimeout but with Macro/Microtasks. What I need is to queue a microtask within a macrotask so that the microtask is executed before the following macrotask.

Do you know a way of scheduling a MacroTask inside NodeJS (I thought setTimeout would do that but unfortunately it seems not to do that)

Comment: I see.  Not sure about that.

Comment: Thank you for you time!
If it's true that we cannot control how vendors implement their engine, it's also true that the concepts of Macro and Microtasks are not vendor specific. And that Microtasks queue should be empty before running the next Macrotask.

So, although understading your point of view, I'm hopping to get a bit more information (and knowledge!) on how does this actually should work.

Comment: The article I posted by Jake explains how and why you are seeing this behavior.  If you want to optimize performance by using macro/micro, perhaps the question should be how to work with the results even if the order is different...

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, but just clarifying, what I'm looking for is to have on NodeJS the same results I have in Chrome. Your answer actually provides the other way around (gives the results I have on Node also on Chrome). I appreciate the effort but it's still not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @jpsfs I set the timeout in the chain  They both output the same on node and chrome for me now.  Probably not ideal or what you want, but it solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying I got it right, I wrote something adhoc and I'd like you to test the below:

**the wrapper:**

```
function order(){
    this.tasks = [];
    this.done = false;
    this.currentIndex = 0;
    this.ignited = false;
}
order.prototype.push = function(f){
    var that =  this,
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(1);
    if(this._currentCaller){
        this.tasks.splice(
            this.tasks.indexOf(this._currentCaller) + 1 + (this.currentIndex++),
            0,
            function(){that._currentCaller = f; f.apply(this,args);}
        );
    } else {
        this.tasks.push(function(){that._currentCaller = f; f.apply(this,args);});
    }
    !this.ignited && (this.ignited = true) && this.ignite();
    return this;
}
order.prototype.ignite = function(){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(that.tasks.length){
            that.tasks[0]();
            that.tasks.shift();
            that.repeat(function(){that.reset(); that.ignite()});
        } else {
            that.ignited = false;
            that.reset();
        }
    },0);
}
order.prototype.repeat = function(f){
    var that = this;
    if(this.done || !this.tasks.length){
        f();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){that.repeat(f);},0);
    }
}
order.prototype.reset = function(){
    this.currentIndex = 0; 
    delete this._currentCaller; 
    this.done = false;
}
```

**to use:**

create an instance:

```
var  x = new order;
```

then modify the rest a bit:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    x.push(function(i){
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Timeout ", i);
            x.push(function(i){
                Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                    console.log("Promise 1 ", i);
                }).then(() => {
                    console.log("Promise 2 ", i);
                    x.done = true;
                })
            },i);
            x.done = true;
        });
    },i);
}
```

I get this:

```
Timeout  0
Promise 1  0
Promise 2  0
Timeout  1
Promise 1  1
Promise 2  1
```

You can even elaborate a bit:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    x.push(function(i){
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Timeout ", i);
            x.push(function(i){
                Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                    console.log("Promise 1 ", i);
                }).then(() => {
                    console.log("Promise 2 ", i);
                    x.done = true;
                })
            },i)
            .push(function(i){
                Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                    console.log("Promise 1 ", i);
                }).then(() => {
                    console.log("Promise 2 ", i);
                    x.done = true;
                })
            },i+0.5)
            .push(function(i){
                Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                    console.log("Promise 1 ", i);
                }).then(() => {
                    console.log("Promise 2 ", i);
                    x.done = true;
                })
            },i+0.75);
            x.done = true;
        });
    },i);
}
```

In node v6, you get:

```
Timeout  0
Promise 1  0
Promise 2  0
Promise 1  0.5
Promise 2  0.5
Promise 1  0.75
Promise 2  0.75
Timeout  1
Promise 1  1
Promise 2  1
Promise 1  1.5
Promise 2  1.5
Promise 1  1.75
Promise 2  1.75
```

Would you try this in your node version for me? In my node (6.11, I know its old) it works.

**Tested on chrome, firefox, node v6.11**

**Note:** you don't have to keep reference to 'x', `this` within the pushed functions refer to the `order` instance. You can also use `Object.defineProperties` to render getters/setters unconfigurable, to prevent accidental deletion of `instance.ignited` etc.